# How to pass data between parent component and child component in angular 4?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular5, angular-router

I have a scenario, I would like to pass data from parent component to child component where Services are to be injected only in Parent Component, all the child components are assigned to router links, can make use of @input property but not sure how to use input properties along with `<router-outlet>`.

I figured out a way to subscribe to router events and in parent component and use conditionals to show the child components, but this is not working as expected!

can anyone offer advice?

Comment: have you considered using a service to share data?

Comment: @pixelbits Service is only injected in parent component

Comment: DId you consider sharing data with routeparams ?

Comment: Why is the service only allowed to be injected into the parent?